# ًHow is stepNumber variable set to lower value, than history.length? (Tic-Tac-Toe by Dan Abramov)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand [code of Tic-Tac-Toe](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gWWZgR) written by Dan Abramov, and I don't see how that code knows the right stepNumber after clicking "Go to Move #n" button and then clicking on a square of the board.

```
// handleClick function:

  handleClick(i) {
    const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
    const current = history[history.length - 1];
    const squares = current.squares.slice();
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
    this.setState({
      history: history.concat([
        {
          squares: squares
        }
      ]),
      stepNumber: history.length,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext
    });
  }
```

If I click a square, this function works, and sets `stepNumber` variable to `history.length` again,

This is the function that is invoked when one clicks a "Go to Move #n" button, and it sets `stepNumber` to the index of the button

```
  jumpTo(step) {
    this.setState({
      stepNumber: step,
      xIsNext: (step % 2) === 0
    });
  }
```

Now, that part is confusing, when go to a previous step in the game, `stepNumber` can be for example 1 and then if I click a square it should set `stepNumber` to for instance 6 (current length of the history array), which would restore all previous values of 'X's and 'O's in their corresponding squares, but it doesn't do so. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that crucial part of this logic is the first line of handleClick function:

```
 const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
```

If you set stepNumber to 3 after clicking on "go to move #3" and then click on an empty square on the board, then only **part of the history till stepNumber** gets copied and rest gets discarded.

You can read up on [Array.slice() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).